# How to rotate bone on fixed axis in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to rotate a bone parallel to a direction vector in world space in THREE JS, but the bone is rotated on the local axis. The local axis keeps on changing as the parent of the bone changes. Is there any way to align a bone as an independent entity in world space that is not influenced by its parent bone?

```
leftArm.applyQuaternion(arrowHelperArm.quaternion)
leftForeArm.applyQuaternion(arrowHelperForeArm.quaternion)
```

The forearm is rotated in the wrong direction as the quaternion is applied taking the local axis as a reference (which is changed when parent is rotated ) whereas I want to apply quaternion taking world axis as a reference.